# Switching Rails app from SQLite to Postgres for local development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, postgresql

I have a little Rails app that is deployed on Heroku. They require a Postgres database, which was not a problem to switch from SQLite3 on their side, but now I can't develop locally without pushing to Heroku every time I want to see changes. I downloaded and installed all of the Postgres assets including the little MenuBar app that keeps a server running and have been all over documentation. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

try this

write in your gemfile

```
group :development do
  gem "sqlite3"
end
group :production do
 gem 'pg'
end
```

when you are working on development mode then it used sqlite3 
and while you are working on production mode then it used pg

Comment: i tried that and it didnt seem to work. is there a specific way to get into "development mode" #n00b